# Check number and written amount don't match

Tags: check

What happens to a check that says $[570-] where the written amount goes and 
"five hundred -------------------70/100" where the written portion goes?

Comment: [Related Question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13372/what-if-i-received-a-check-with-two-different-amounts-written-on-it-words-vs-n)

Answer (score 0):

In most jurisdictions, such a check would (should) be bounced. It would be considered invalid.